# Generating huge amounts of HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a browser game. I have lots of upgrades, crafting, planets, etc that I generate with jS (1 box (or square?) PER EACH item). Here is a mini snippet from my game, displaying my current method of generating HTML

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/MiloSx7/7L8e5kmg/1/)

I do a simple loop and insert as many boxes as there are upgrades

```
for(i = 0; i < 9; i ++)
```

Then, I put a gigantic HTML code block in a function, and use arrays to identify upgrades ID, name, info...

Is this a good practice to generate loads of HTML content? If not, what can I do to improve it?

Also, I started "coding" a game with one main goal to learn JS. If you have better solutions, but they include a lib (jQuery, etc) then you can post it, but I'm going pure jS here. Thanks!

-- Update --

I've been learning lots of JS in the past year. @DoXicK provided a great example a while ago but I didn't understand it then. This is the final rendering method I come up with, thanks to his examples, and I guess I'll stick with it:

JS:

```
const game = {};
// make our life easier
const $ = key => document.getElementById(key);
const render = (key, str) => $(key).insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", str);
// a function that returns upgrades html content
const html = self => `
  <div class="some-class" id="${self.id}">
    <h2>${self.name}</h2>
    <p>${self.damage}</p>
  </div>
`;
// object containing each upgrades template
const template = {
  laserGun: {
    id: "laserGun",
    name: "Laser Gun",
    damage: 10
  },
  plasmaGun: {
    id: "plasmaGun",
    name: "Plasma Gun",
    damage: 30
  }
};
// Upgrade class
class Upgrade {
  constructor(upg) {
    this._id = upg.id;
    this._name = upg.name;
    this._damage = upg.damage;
  }

  get id() {return this._id;}
  get name() {return this._name;}
  get damage() {return this._damage;}

  generate() {
    // find div with upgrade id, and inject it's html content inside
    render("upgrade", html(this));
  }

  static make(key) {
    game.upgrade[key] = new Upgrade(template[key]);
    game.upgrade[key].generate();
  }
}

let laserGun = Upgrade.make("laserGun");
```

HTML:

```
<div class="upgrade-container" id="upgrade">
```

I hope you find it helpful!

Comment: Concept seems reasonably sound

Comment: My only suggestion would be to use [ES6 template strings](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings) for your interpolation. It makes things more readable, IMHO.

Comment: I was just checking ES6 the other day. I will give it another look. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a good practice to generate HTML, no. It will become terribly slow and an unmaintainable blob of code in the end. If you want to go full on javascript, use template strings. My tip: make a toolset that generates HTML for you based on javascript. (take a look at hyperscript for an example)

Comment: You might want to store the upgrades in an array of objects, one per upgrade rather than multiple arrays. That way you keep the data together and I think it makes it much more readable.

Comment: @DoXicK I was thinking the same thing. my generateHTML.js file already has well above 700 lines and looks like a mess. On a hosted server takes a year to load up.
DBS neat idea, might try something like that

Comment: jQuery also have some nice functions to build elements. Altough im not sure how efficient it is.

Comment: I suggest [<template>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

Comment: Generally, HTML should define the _structure_, JavaScript should define the _behaviour_ and CSS should define the _style_ of your application. [Source: ppk on JavaScript]

Comment: @MiloSx7 depending on how far you are in javascript, es6 classes work reasonable well with this. Make a class you can use to encapsulate a "module". taking your example: `new UpdateBlock({id: xxx, name: xxx, description: xxx});`. That UpgradeBlock you can sub-class from BaseComponent which has a render function which returns the html it generates. That way, you encapsulate every block as a standalone, testable component

Comment: My personal preference is `<script type="text/html"><div>Template here</div></script>`

Comment: You might want to look into angular. You can then have loops in your HTML, use templates, etc. Note also that if you have a very large number of items, it may not make sense to render them all at once (or at least not completely, e.g. load all images). You might want to look into lazy loading in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i already explained in comments, your code will become quite unmaintainable if you keep it as spaghetti code like that.

I've made an updated example which does the exact same thing as you did, just with a bit of updated javascript and by making a javascript-component out of your "template".

https://jsfiddle.net/7L8e5kmg/3/

```
class UpgradeBlock {
    constructor(props) {
      this.props = props;
  }
  render() {
    let { Id, Name, Info, Res } = this.props;
    // basically:
    // let Id = this.props.Id;
    // let Name = this.props.Name;
    // etc
    return (`
<div class="hud-item" id="${Id}">
    <img src="client/img/${Id}.png" id="${Id}Img" />
    <div class="hud-tooltip f16 fwhite">
        <div class="hud-tt-header-container">
            <div class="hud-tt-info-container">
                <div class="col-full">${Name}</div>
                <div class="col-half">
                    <img style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" src="img/${Res}16.png" />
                  <span id="${Id}Cost"></span>
                                </div>
                <div class="col-half">
                    +<span id="${Id}dmgPerLv"></span>
                  <img style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" src="client/img/character/dps16.png" />
                                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hud-tt-lv-container">
                <canvas id="${Id}Bar" width="64px" height="64px"></canvas>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="hud-tt-info-container">
            <div class="col-half fwhite f16">
                <img style="vertical-align: text-bottom" src="client/img/character/dps16.png" />
              <span id="${Id}Dmg"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-half fgrey f10"><span class="fwhite f16" id="${Id}ofTotal"></span> of total</div>
            <div class="col-full fgrey f10">${Info}</div>
            <div class="col-full f10" id="${Id}click"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    `)
  }
}
```

You use it by doing:

```
let upgrade = {
  Id: 'id', 
  Name: 'name',
  Info: 'info',
  Res: 'res'
};
let html = new UpgradeBlock(upgrade).Render()
```

For people that do react: yes, it is intended to steer that way.

Comment: Thanks, this actually looks a lot more cleaner and readable. Neat, good job

Comment: i would even abstract it more btw, but this gives a good starting point of how you can make sure you don't end up with a huge wad of code. And this way, you also don't run into conflicts between scripts that overwrite variables etc. Glad it helps :-)

Comment: Hey, sorry for disturbing, is there any way I can get the Id only, from a specified upgrade from the list?

Comment: I was able to do it with `var ID = UPGRADES[num].Id;`
Now all my boxes have display:none attr, and they get unlocked periodically, as game progresses. So that should lower the loading time even further i think

Comment: Since it's an array of objects, you can use `Array.find(..)` on it to find a certain upgrade. Just using the index like you did also works. I would let a box that has display none, just `return ''` in its render method... makes it easier to maintain again (the concern of the object stays in the component), or let it add a class to it, which then has `display: none`. For instance: `hud-item--disabled` (this naming convention comes from BEM, worth googling)

Comment: sorry to bump this ancient post, tho I've been doing loads of digging into JS ever since, and I've gotten marginally better! I've been regularly checking your post trying to figure out what your code actually does, and right now, I think I finally get it. Except for the`upgrades.map(upgrade => new UpgradeBlock(upgrade).render()).join('')` Could you explain a little more what this line does? For the time being I used `insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '_html content_')`, which worked OK, but I guess it can always be done better. I see you're doing return there, what's the difference? Thanks!

Comment: @MiloSx7 of course: The `return` returns a string. so `new UpgradeBlock(upgrade).render()` returns a string. `upgrades.map(.....)` returns an array with strings. To output that, you want to make that into 1 string: `Array.join('')` joins the items of the array with `''` in between each items. So it will basically become `string + '' + string + '' + string ......`. Does that answer your question ?

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty clear now. I keep my upgrades in an object instead of an array now, passing object instances in the constructor, and generating new upgrades as they need to be unlocked, instead of having them all generated at once and hidden if not unlocked. Classes do work great for this, it's just that I steered away from them until I fully understood "this" and prototype. I like that render function similar to React, I'll do rendering that way. Thanks for the response!